# согласование сказуемого

Tags: согласование

Здравствуйте.
Очень нужен ответ специалиста. Как правильно:
Его нездоровая бледность *была* первое, что бросалось в глаза.
или
Его нездоровая бледность *было* первое, что бросалось в глаза.
И почему? Совсем запуталась.
Заранее благодарна за ответ.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5):

Его нездоровая бледность было первое, что бросалось в глаза.

В этом виде - средний род, потому что бледность - это первое, что бросалось в глаза.

Но: Его нездоровая бледность была первЫМ, что бросалось в глаза.

Comment: Это во что это Вы превратили мой ответ? Верните, пожалуйста, его прежний вид.

Comment: Интересно, здесь модератором может быть любой, кто пожелает? Видна закономерность: чем менее грамотный участник, тем более рьяно он модерирует.

Comment: Людмила, я вернул исходное. Да Вы это сами можете делать.

Comment: *Интересно, здесь модератором может быть любой, кто пожелает?* - Да, при определенном цензе кармы. Это концепция ресурса.

Comment: Спасибо, уважаемый  behemothus

Comment: Я вообще не вижу смысла во всех этих исправлениях. Мои ответы часто  исправляют, пыталась проследить, что именно не понравилось, - это выше моих способностей: то пробел поставят, то вообще ничего не исправлено, а изменение есть. Лучше бы указали, что не так печатаю, чтоб не допускать этих ошибок.

Comment: Я потом посмотрел, первым восстановил справедливость ***Серж***, а я на него подумал, что это он тут наисправлял. Так что спасибо ему передайте. )))  А насчет смысла - редактирование дано для исправления мелких ошибок и опечаток, нарушающих понимание. Ну и для формата под общий стиль ресурса. К сожалению, иногда палку явно перегибают. Я о том вопрос на мете поднимал, но меня "вежливо и культурно" отправили восвояси.   К сожалению, с вандальной правкой совершенно невозможно бороться.

Comment: Я согласен, что написать об ошибке куда правильнее, если автор - "живой" и активный. Следить за правками не надо, если видите, что лучше не стало, просто откатывайте свою версию. для этого надо нажать на строчке "изменен..." над "граватаром" последнего изменившего - вот сейчас над картинкой с моим фирменным зверем и надписью   "изменён 13 часов назад behemothus"

Answer (score 2):

(1) Его нездоровая бледность - **это (было) первое**, что бросалось  глаза.

Это простое предложение с именным сказуемым. Во всех других вариантах **не устраняется конфликт среднего и женского рода.**

Рассмотрим вариант (2):  Его нездоровая бледность // **было первое,** что бросалось  глаза.

Вариант (2) ближе всего к варианту (1), так как  в этом случае группу подлежащего и сказуемого **можно разделить паузой**.

Answer (score 1):

Если выбирать из двух вариантов, то однозначно второй:

"Его нездоровая бледность было первое, что бросалось в глаза".

Как возможные варианты:

"Его нездоровая бледность была первой деталью (или особенностью), которая бросалась в глаза".

Comment: Вопрос не в том, что выбрать, а в объяснении грамматики обоих вариантов .

Comment: Я читать умею, вопрос читал. )) Вопрос был: "Как правильно?" Где тут про грамматику?

Comment: Вопрос и правда про грамматику. Возможно, мое "И почему?" оказалось не слишком понятным, но мне действительно нужно не просто мнение, а обоснование. Ведь всем ясно, что подлежащее должно согласовываться со сказумемым, но здесь этого как-то не получается... Возможно, Людмила была права и правомерны два (ее) варианта, но если использовать средний род, то я бы поставила тире: "Его нездоровая бледность - было первое, что...." Тире как раз замещает пропущенное "это". Но уверенности в правильности данного варианта по-прежнему нет.

Comment: Теперь я вас понял. К сожалению, вынужден признать, что я более всего интуитивист, всегда писал правильно, но когда, к примеру, учитель в школе спрашивал, почему я написал именно так, всегда мучился с ответом... Возможно, как мне говорили, дело в моей памяти и в том, что я много читал. Так что по поводу грамматики могу сказать честно: не смогу вам ответить. Здесь есть более крутые и знающие специалисты (без иронии). А по поводу вашего варианта ("бледность - было первое, что...")... лично мне кажется, что тире все же лишнее. Ведь там есть "было". Вот не будь его, тогда - да, тире... ))

Comment: Получила ответ на другом лингвистическом сайте (от специалистов). Публикую для всех, кого затронула эта тема.   
Предпочтительно писать:  
"Его нездоровая бледность - это было первое, что..."  
Как вариант возможно:
"Его нездоровая бледность была первым, что..."  
Кому что больше нравится.

Answer (score 0):

Если возможен вариант

```
Его нездоровая бледность была первым, что...
```

то странно было бы отказывать в корректности варианту с другим падежом в сказуемом

```
Его нездоровая бледность была первое, что...
```

Так как наличие двух падежей в "дополнении-сказуемом" это традиционная возможность у глагола быть.

```
В. Ф. Ходасевич. Державин (1929-1931)    [омонимия не снята]   Все примеры (1)  
Прямота была главное в нем.
```